# How to pass multiple parameters from javascript to windows phone methods without using windows.script.Notify()?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

Here I want to pass multiple parameters from javascript to windows phone method. I need to perform this after script_notify is done.

following is C# - Windowsphone code:

```
private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        flyersInfos = "[{\"app_user_id\": \"" + thisapp.AppId + "\",\"flyer_user_id\": \"" + thisapp.FlyersId + "\",\"device_id\": \"" + thisapp.DeviceId + "\",\"device_info\": \"" + thisapp.DeviceInfo + "\",\"Latitude\": \"" + thisapp.Latitude + "\",\"Longitude\": \"" + thisapp.Longitude + "\"}]";

        if (e.Value == "getMemoryUsage")
            Browser.InvokeScript("renderForm", flyersInfos);
        return;
    }
```

javascript Notify Function in Onload(),

```
function onload()
{
  window.external.notify("getMemoryUsage");   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The fast way:

It is a **void** event handler, so you can just make it async and delay it:

```
private async void Browser_ScriptNotify(...)
{
  ...
  await Task.Delay(1);
  ...
  // everything here will execute after the original ScriptNotify event
  // was completely finished, as it continues on the same (UI) thread.
}
```

Proper way would be to use a queue or some messaging implementation.

Comment: It's not like that, first I have to pass the "flyerInfos" values to Javascript side, in that i set app_id and flyers_id will be "0". After that Javascript have to forward real app_Id and Fluyers_id. by using Script_notify i will get those values before i forward "flyerinfos".

Answer (score 0):

You can pass only a single parameter as a `string` from `javascript` to the `C#` class. But in case you need to send more than one parameter, I suggest to **concatenate the parameters with specific delimiter.**

For example, from the javascript:

```
window.external.notify("parameter1+parameter2+parameter3");
```

Here I used a single string as a parameter to send all three. Finally parse the string and rebuild the original three parameters in the `C#` code.